# C++ adding two array items and other errors on run

Tags: c++, arrays, sum

When I compile and run this program, I get different errors mostly regarding the calling of the function and the sum of arrays - I have tried fixing them myself but whenever I fix one problem I seem to never be able to fix them all as more come in then leave.

```
/*
Even Fibonacci numbers
Problem 2
Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:

1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...

By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int increaseArray(int array, int currentPointer, int maxNumber, int arraySize, bool stop, int total);

int main () {
  int arraySize = 2;
  int maxNumber = 4000000;
  int currentPointer = 1;
  int array[2] = {1, 2};
  int total = 0;
  bool stop = false;
  while (not stop) {
    increaseArray(array, currentPointer, maxNumber, arraySize, stop, total);
  }


}

int increaseArray(int array, int currentPointer, int maxNumber, int arraySize, bool stop, int total) {
  int newValue = array[currentPointer - 1] + array[currentPointer - 2];
  while (newValue < maxNumber) {
    arraySize++;
    int *array = new int[arraySize];
    array[arraySize] = newValue;
    if (newValue % 2 == 0) {
       total += newValue;
increaseArray(array, currentPointer, maxNumber, arraySize, stop, total);
}
  stop = true;
  return total;
  }

 };
```

Here are the errors that I am getting:-

error: no matching function for call to 'increaseArray'
increaseArray(array, currentPointer, maxNumber, arraySize, stop, total);
^~~

note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int [2]' to 'int' for 1st argument
int increaseArray(int array, int currentPointer, int maxNumber, int arraySize, bool stop, int total);
^
error: subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector
int newValue = array[currentPointer - 1] + array[currentPointer - 2];
~^~~~~

error: subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector
int newValue = array[currentPointer - 1] + array[currentPointer - 2];
~^~~~~

error: no matching function for call to 'increaseArray'
increaseArray(array, currentPointer, maxNumber, arraySize, stop, total);
^~~

note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int ' to 'int' for 1st argument; dereference the argument with 
int increaseArray(int array, int currentPointer, int maxNumber, int arraySize, bool stop, int total) {
^
4 errors generated.

Comment: The error messages tell you exactly what is wrong: `int increaseArray(int array, ...` should be `int increaseArray(int * array, ...`.

Comment: Changing the parameter doesn't help. `int array[2]` is a fixed size array, and cannot be "increased". You might want to try a `std::vector<int>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the declaration of increaseArray function.
You want to pass as an argument a whole array, but you declare that the first argument is just an integer.
One solution to the problem would be:
int increaseArray(int * array,....).
I would strongly recommend to learn more about passing arrays to functions.
A good place to start would be: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_passing_arrays_to_functions.htm
I hope that helps!